# Does Datastage version 11.x support metadata to be installed in Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, etl, datastage

We are using Oracle  for Datatage metadata and planning to move Postgres, just wanted to know if Datastage metadata can be installed in Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [IBM support site for prerequisites](https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=7FE40FD076CF11E7ACE8EE5CF6073F72&osPlatforms=Linux&duComponentIds=D004%7CS002%7CS001%7CS003&mandatoryCapIds=30%7C47%7C9%7C16%7C26&optionalCapIds=7%7C24%7C70%7C186%7C61)

For 11.7 Postgres is not listed.